# Simple CSS hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a very simple layout here: http://www.flanels.com/ - If you click work it draws down, I am using this jQuery:

```
    $('#left ul li.item').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('over');
    }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('over');
    });
```

And this is the class:

```
#left ul li.over{
    background-color:#4CC7DC;    
}
```

If you go over the link text you see that it changes to the a:hover, I am trying to make it for when you are over the li.item the a:hover link changes as well, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#left ul li.over, #left ul li.over a {
    background-color:#4CC7DC;    
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I can think of as well.

Comment: Hey Chris, that worked great thank you. I see what you did with the selector, its perfect.

Ryan

Comment: Glad I refreshed before second-guessing and trying something with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover()` on the `li.item` element, then instead of accessing `$(this).add/removeClass()` instead access `$('#left ul li.item').add/removeClass()`.

That is, you can set classes on *any* element, not just `$(this)`, so just name the element you want to change.